# I am searching for a multi-level dropdown with checkboxes and multi-select

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sass, dropdown

[Example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AGRLV.png)

For a react project i need a dropdown that looks like the image above.

The problem is that i can't find anything where i can do this.
The idea is that i have a dropdown filled with groups.
And when i check one of the checkboxes the other level opens with options from that group which i can optionally select.

I have tried multiple libraries and i can't get it to work.
And because of the project not being on the latest version of React some libraries don't work because of the dependencies.